# Using stdout from piped command in nc connection and commands in parentheses

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, stdout, pipeline

I want to know how I can use **stdout**  from piped command and then use it in nc connection:

```
<COMMAND> | \
grep -oE '((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' | \
(echo "exit" | nc <IP-HERE> 23 -w 5 \
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
(
<SomeCommandsHERE>
) | nc <IP-HERE> 23 1>>$file 2>&1 )
```

Questions:

1) How can I use result of `grep command` for my `nc` command in this thread?

2) Can I say the result of `grep` that is an **ip** only be used in whole following statement like what I did here?

```
(echo "exit" | nc <IP-HERE> 23 -w 5 \
    if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    (
    <SomeCommandsHERE>
    ) | nc <IP-HERE> 23 1>>$file 2>&1 )
```

## UPDATE

What I tried so far:

```
<COMMAND> | \
grep -oE '((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])' | \
while read ip; do
    ( echo "exit" | nc "$ip" 23 -w 5
    [[ "$?" -eq "0" ]]
        (
            echo "hello"
        ) | nc "$ip" 23 1>>$file 2>&1
    ); done
```

Is this correct? How can I change the `if` statement if it is not corrrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the output of the `<COMMAND>` to a loop, you could evaluate it one line at a time:

```
<COMMAND> | while read text; do
  ipaddr=`echo $text | grep -oE '((1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])\.){3}(1?[0-9][0-9]?|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])'`
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    (echo "exit" | nc $ipaddr 23 -w 5 
      if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       (
         <SomeCommandsHERE>
       ) | nc $ipaddr 23 1>>$file 2>&1 
      fi
    )        
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you... :) ... please see my update... Is the update correct as well?

Comment: actually, this will only work if `<COMMAND>` outputs an IP address on a line by itself with no other text or punctuation.

Comment: Thank you.I am checjing your solution...for letting other guys to know please add `'` at the end of grep command

Comment: Pardon me. Does this solution check each ip just one time not more?

Comment: it will check each ip each time `<COMMAND>` outputs it

Comment: Ok but the `<COMMAND>` is appending lines each time, so ips are going to be checked repetidly  :( ... when I run script the error occurs like: `syntax error near unexpected token `then'       if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then'
`

Comment: There was a stray `\\` - I've removed it now.

Comment: When I removed parentheses for ` (echo "exit" | nc $ipaddr 23 -w 5 ` the error disappeared, But you are correct as well.. I am chching